# Line wrapping in Eclipse Java formatter

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting, format, formatter

I'm trying to configure the Java code formatter to have a compact formatting. I've set the policy to "Wrap where necessary", and maximum line width to 80, but either it wraps where it shouldn't, or it doesn't wrap where it should... Here is an example of what I get:

```
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------80->
public class FormatterTest {
    void test() {
        int i, a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, d = 1;
        i =
                a
                        * b
                        * c
                        * d
                        * (100000000 + 100000000 + 100000000 + 100000000
                                + 100000000 + 100000000 + 100000000 + 100000000 + 100000000);
    }
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------80->
```

And what I'd like:

```
    i = a * b * c * d * (100000000 + 100000000 + 100000000 + 100000000
            + 100000000 + 100000000 + 100000000 + 100000000 + 100000000);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: for which kind of statement have you set to Wrap where necessary?

Comment: I would think this way, if a modern code formatter like one in Eclipse  is not able to format the code correctly. That might means something wrong in that code, this issue should be solve by improve the code, not formatter.

Comment: I don't know if Eclipse is modern but its formatter is not able to format simple expressions. I think it's too easy to pretend it's my code. I have the same problem with code from other projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress the formatting if you add an `//` at the end of the line:

```
i = a * b * c * d * (100000000 + 100000000 + 100000000 + 100000000 //
        + 100000000 + 100000000 + 100000000 + 100000000 + 100000000);
```

Comment: @Patrick: It should be an absolute exception to use this workaround. If you need it in bulk, you maybe have a problem which your coding style. Anyway, a line width of 80 is not contemporary in times of cheap 24" monitors in my opinion.

Comment: @user714965 agree, we have a common formatter that set the max width=150. also an alternative to ignore formatting is //@formatter:off and then //@formatter:on.

Comment: The problem is exactly the same (only less frequent) with line width set to 150.

Answer (score 0):

well in comment you said "expressions", there are different kind of expressions. check the screenshot. I think it (example codes by eclipse at right side) looks like what you want.

hope it is helpful.

[image]

**EDIT**

could you try

```
 expressions-> Assignments :Do not wrap
```

Comment: Sorry but I tried different configurations with different kind of expressions, but I can't get a correct formatting. It's OK in the preview but not in my code (in my example, all expression types are set to Wrap where necessary).

Comment: some expression type you don't have to set to wrap. check my updates. hope it helps.

Comment: It's a little better but not that much, it still wraps where it shouldn't and doesn't wrap where it should. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it formatted in my Eclipse as follows, using the "Java Conventions [built-in]" formatter settings:

```
public class FormatterTest {
    void test() {
    int i, a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, d = 1;
    i = (a * b * c * d * (100000000 + 100000000 + 100000000 + 100000000
        + 100000000 + 100000000 + 100000000 + 100000000 + 100000000));
    }
}
```

For some reason, the brackets around the entire expression are essential. Without them, I get completely different formatting.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice hack, but still a hack. I'm afraid the formatted is buggy.